# Magento 2 : Contact us email is not sending to admin

Tags: magento2, contact-us

I have checked with all latest and oldest version of magento 2 but contact us email is not sending to admin.

I have already set the configuration in admin with admin email and etc.

I am getting rest all the emails like registration, newsletter subscription etc. but don't get contact us email.

Comment: Can you look at the log files?

Comment: Yes i have checked there is no logs related to this. May its magento 2 default issue.

Comment: contact us email is not sent to admin you need to custom code the logic of sending email to admin.!

Answer (score 3):

I think you forgot to set contact mail id. Please check can you set admin mail id in contact tab? if not just set. Magento 2 not issue in Contact us.

[image]

Comment: This is not the issue! Mine is configured and I have cleared all of the cache and etc. but it keeps sending to: 1BD1882D0C    11669 Tue Feb 12 17:33:46  no-reply@somedomain.com
              (connect to example.com[93.184.216.34]:25: Connection timed out)
                                         hello@example.com

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I figured out that if you done have a valid template, (install without sampled data) it wont sent the email, and it will not put out any message.

So make sure you have a valid email template.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is reading this and has this issue, I changed the 'Email Sender' to "General Contact" and it started working (mine was set to "Custom Email 2")